# Relation between azure_managed_disk and storage_data_disk

Tags: azure, azure-storage, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Please look at the terraform code block below: It is adding 5 disks to each VM each of 1 TB, correct?

```
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "tf-mdsk-cluster" {
  count                = 5
  name                 = "${var.ax_base_hostname}-${count.index+1}-DATADISK"
  location             = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-internal.location}"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-internal.name}"
  storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  create_option        = "Empty"
  disk_size_gb         = "1024"
}
```

If yes then what is done below? The below terraform code is also adding 2 disks each of 1 TB for 5 VM's so which one I should use?

```
storage_data_disk {
  name            = "${var.ax_base_hostname}-${count.index+1}-DISK-0"
  managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  create_option   = "Empty"
  lun             = 0
  disk_size_gb    = "1023"
}

storage_data_disk {
  name            = "${var.ax_base_hostname}-${count.index+1}-DISK-1"
  managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  create_option   = "Empty"
  lun             = 1
  disk_size_gb    = "1023"
}
```

I am totally confused about what is the role of each and which should be used. My requirement is all disk that includes OS disk and Data disk should be managed disk. Data disk should be 5 TB for each VM, I have to build 5 VM's. Understand that this could be achieved with scale set but because of the application, we are using a cluster of 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe one is explicitly creating the managed disk resources, while the other is just a vm definition (vm will create those disks for you). so the same result can be achieved using different approaches.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine.html#storage_data_disk

Comment: no. attach - attaches existing disk (so it has to exist beforehand)

Comment: Actually the requirement is to create from scratch and then attach to VM. So they don't exist before.

Comment: that means you need to use both just like in the example you gave

Comment: just to clarify, use `azurerm_managed_disk` to create disks, then use `storage_data_disk` with attach option to attach newly created disks